# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/amcharts4 - Not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to install npm package dependencies into my angular application and i'm getting this error. Any help to fix this?

```
C:\Users\TM161\Desktop\Master\stage PFE\SNRT-Music>npm i
    npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/amcharts4 - Not found
    npm ERR! 404
    npm ERR! 404  'amcharts4@latest' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\TM161\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-02T15_41_58_935Z-debug.log
```

Comment: In you package.json there is a package name that is not known by the public npm registry. The closest package that i could find to "amcharts4" is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@amcharts/amcharts4. Does it fit your needs ?

Comment: It still the same problem, when i try to install amcharts.

Answer (score 0):

npm can not find amcharts4 package in the regisry. Your package version might be older. So try

```
npm i @amcharts/amcharts4
```

then `npm i`

Comment: I already try this, but it still the same problem !!